How to use Bootstrap Icons in Blazor
I attempted to follow this article to add icons to my app: https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2021/01/07/bootstrap-icons-1-3-0/
So I included the Bootstrap Icons font stylesheet in the Head of App.razor:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyApp.styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">     
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>

Then tried to use an icon, such as: https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/0-circle/
<NavLink class="nav-link" href="Account/SignIn">
       <i class="bi bi-0-circle"></i>
       <span class="nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Sign In
</NavLink>

But the icon is not showing. I also tried:
<span class="bi bi-0-circle nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Sign In

What am I doing wrong?

Bootstrap Icons 1.3.0 is considered a quite old version with its release was on 4 years ago. Based on the Bootstrap Icons doc, shows all the icons supported in the latest version (1.11.0).
In the 1.3.0, you can search the word "0-circle" but unfortunately it doesn't exist.
While the same searching approach is used in 1.11.0, it is supported.
Hence, you have to use the latest Bootstrap Icons (1.11.0).
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css"> 

